# Selecting row from a table that doesn't have another similar one, not fulfilling condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sorry for the messy title, but I didn't know how to explain it without an example. Let's say I've got a table:

```
ID | A
-------
1  | X
1  | Y
2  | X
3  | X
```

I would want to select all rows that for given ID have only value X in the column A, and not Y. So in this case I would get:

```
ID | A
-------
2  | X
3  | X
```

I don't know how to construct such query. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `not exists`

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id = t.id and t2.a <> 'X'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Below would be one way -

```
select * from table where id in (select id from table group by id having count(*)=1) and id='X'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do aggregation :

```
SELECT ID, 'X' AS A
FROM table t
GROUP BY ID
HAVING MIN(A) = MAX(A) AND MIN(A) = 'X';
```

If you want all columns then you can also use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE t.A = 'X' AND -- have only value "X" 
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.ID = t.ID AND t1.A = 'Y');
```